# Does token-2022 allow transfer fees in SOL instead of a token?

Tags: transactions, token-2022, swap

That is, the receiver of a fee should get a fee not in a token but in SOL. Is it supported by token-2022?

I'm aware of **transfer hook**. Would one use it, send a TX to a DEX such as Raydium?

Otherwise, how else?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you need to use a transfer hook to assess a transfer fee in SOL. The transfer fees built into token-2022 are denominated in the same token, and you cannot configure some other mint directly in token-2022.

So you'll have to [use a transfer hook](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-hook#transfer-hook-with-wsol-transfer-fee-advanced-example).

Comment: I need the fees to be paid in SOL only. Perhaps, by making a request to DEX. Will this work?